# Integer exponentiation algorithm for the special case $3^n$

Tags: algorithms, exponentiation

Is there any known integer exponentiation algorithm to compute $x^y$ for the special case $x = 3$ which is faster than the general case algorithm found in [1], section 4.6.3?

[1] D. E. Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming. Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms, Addison-Wesley, 1981

Comment: Depends. How do you want the result? If trinary notation is acceptable, you can get it in linear time by outputting an `1` followed by $y$ `0`s.

Comment: Is Knuth talking about the squaring algorithm in Section 4.6.3 of the Volume 2?

Comment: @Henning: That's just silly! Because it works for any $x$, doesn't it? Not just $x=3$. "Give me $x^y$ in base $x$".

Comment: @Simone: I believe so even though I don't have the referenced print physically available.

Comment: @TonyK: Yes, it's a bit silly -- but there's a point to the silliness, namely that the achievable efficiency depends on which representation is required for the result, so the OP should not expect a precise answer without specifying a representation first.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: That's correct. The referenced Knuth's algorithm exploits the binary representation of the exponent, so let me clarify - I need the binary result to work with it in an ordinary binary computer.